# Formatting based on multiple cells and duplicates

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I will try my best to explain the situation :

I have a sheet where we enter test data and serial numbers.

- `Column A` is serial number
- `Column C` is if the unit passed or not.

I currently have conditionalformatting to highlight duplicate serial numbers (based on `Column A`).

Because we fix and
   retest failed units we get duplicates of serial numbers where one has
   `pass` in `column C` and the other has `fail`.

**What I would like to do** is :
  Have the sheet find **duplicates** but **only highlight** when **both
   duplicates** have "pass" in `column C`.

I have tried both [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and [conditional-formatting](/questions/tagged/conditional-formatting), I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: Maybe something like `=COUNTIFS(B:B; B1; A:A; A1 )>1` ? maybe cross-sites duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899516/how-to-highlight-cell-if-value-duplicate-in-same-column-for-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about you create another column and concatenate A and C, then do this:

```
=Countif(D:D,D1)>1
```

When you concatenate serial and pass/notpassed you have a unique value for serial A-pass and serial A-"not passed" and then you can countif them

Comment: That worked, I would have never thought to do it that way. Thank you.

Comment: Many times you will see the need of adding a new column with some extra data you'd need to do what you want to achieve